# Why is s3 giving me a download instead of displaying my static website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static-site

I'm trying to setup a static page on s3 with these [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).  When I access the "Endpoint", my browser tries to download the file instead of displaying the page.  Here's the relevant settings:

## Policies:

[image]

---

## Permissions:

[image]

---

## Static Site Config:

[image]

---

## Directory Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the headers/metadata on your index.html file?

Comment: @datasage: http://cl.ly/image/0U120Z453N1Q

Comment: This link here is most likely your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296875/amazon-s3-downloads-index-html-instead-of-serving

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the bucket name needs to match the domain.  In the [documentation you linked](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html), the walkthrough creates two buckets: **example.com** and **www.example.com**.  example.com bucket contains your website contents, while www.example.com is configured to route to example.com bucket.

Looking at your images, it looks like you named your bucket 'rampup-io'.  You need to change this bucket name to match your domain: **yourdomain.com**.  You have the option to create **www.yourdomain.com**.

Comment: It's true that they say that on the documentation, but they also provide an ending point that should allow you to see the content. I don't think this solves the issue.