# Amazon S3 downloads index.html instead of serving

Tags: amazon-s3

I've set up Amazon S3 to serve my static site, `speakeasylinguistics.com`. All of the DNS stuff seems to be working okay, because `dig +recurse +trace www.speakeasylinguistics.com` outputs the correct DNS info.

But when you [visit the site in a browser](http://speakeasylinguistics.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com) using the endpoint, the `index.html` page downloads, instead of being served. How do I fix this?

I've tried Chrome, Safari, FF. It happens on all of them. I used [Amazon's walkthrough](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) on hosting a custom domain to a T.

Comment: running curl -I against the file returns: `Content-Disposition: attachment` in the headers -- that is what is causing the problem. I *think* that is in the meta data for the file.

Comment: I solved this problem specifying the metadata (content-type = text/html) when uploading the html file to S3

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Running curl -I against the url you posted gives the following result:

```
curl -I http://speakeasylinguistics.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: DmfUpbglWQ/evhF3pTiXYf6c+gIE8j0F6mw7VmATOpfc29V5tb5YTeojC68jE7Rd
x-amz-request-id: E233603809AF9956
Date: Sun, 18 Aug 2013 07:58:55 GMT
Content-Disposition: attachment
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Aug 2013 07:05:20 GMT
ETag: "eacded76ceb4831aaeae2805c892fa1c"
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2585
Server: AmazonS3
```

This line is the culprit:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

If you are using the AWS console, I believe this can be changed by selecting the file in S3 and modifying its meta data by removing this property.

Comment: I'm facing this issue without the "Content-Disposition" parameter defined. However, I noticed this setting ```content-type: application/x-directory; charset=UTF-8``` and I suspect this could be the issue. 

Is there a way I can change it to `text/html` ?

Comment: How to remove the property ?

Answer (score 69):

If you are using [Hashicorp Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) you can specify the `content-type` on an [aws_s3_bucket_object](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_object.html) as follows

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "index" {
  bucket = "yourbucketnamehere"
  key = "index.html"
  content = "<h1>Hello, world</h1>"

  content_type = "text/html"
}
```

This should serve your content appropriately in the browser.

*Edit 24/05/22:* As mentioned in the comments on this answer, Terraform [now has a module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/dir/template/latest) to help with uploading files and setting their `content-type` attribute correctly

Comment: Thank you for the Terraform mention!

Comment: Terraform documentation should have mentioned it.

Comment: terraform def doesn't mention this clearly. thanks for this!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. Also to add, due to some caches, if one keep retrying the website endpoint, the issue would appear to still exist. Try doing it in incognito or after clearing caches, it will serve the content on the browser.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is exactly the detail I needed.  Was driving me crazy! :D  Thanks, mate!

Comment: and if you're using cloudfront, make sure you create an invalidation, to drop the cache

Comment: There is a new way of identifying content type in Terraform. I followed this example, but it still downloaded the html file because the metadata - system defined - content-type was set to binary. This answer fixed the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456167/uploading-multiple-files-in-aws-s3-from-terraform/58827910#58827910

Answer (score 33):

If you are doing this programmatically you can set the `ContentType` and/or `ContentDisposition` params in your upload.

[PHP Example]

```
      $output = $s3->putObject(array(
          'Bucket' => $bucket,
          'Key' => md5($share). '.html',
          'ContentType' => 'text/html',
          'Body' => $share,
      ));
```

[putObject Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject)

Answer (score 14):

For anyone else facing this issue, there's a typo in the URL you can find under `Properties > Static website hosting`. For instance, the URL provided is

```
http://{bucket}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com
```

but it should be

```
http://{bucket}.s3-website.{region}.amazonaws.com
```

Note the `.` between `website` and `region`.

Comment: This fixed it for me, Thanks.

Comment: I actually have **-** from aws and not **.**. So aws code is buggy, not cool

Answer (score 13):

if you guys are trying to upload it with Boto3 and python 3.7 or above try with

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
S3.upload_file(local_file,bucket,S3_file,ExtraArgs={'ContentType':'text/html'})
```

for update Content-Type

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when uploading to an S3 static site from NodeJS. As others have mentioned, the issue was caused by missing the `content-type` when uploading the file. When using the web interface, the `content-type` is automatically applied for you; however, when manually uploading you will need to specify it. [List of S3 Content Types](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aspera-on-cloud?topic=resources-aws-s3-content-types).

In NodeJS, you can attach the content type like so:

```
const { extname } = require('path');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');

// add more types as needed
const getMimeType = ext => {
    switch (ext) {
        case '.js':
            return 'application/javascript';
        case '.html':
            return 'text/html';
        case '.txt':
            return 'text/plain';
        case '.json':
            return 'application/json';
        case '.ico':
            return 'image/x-icon';
        case '.svg':
            return 'image/svg+xml';
        case '.css':
            return 'text/css'
        case '.jpg':
        case '.jpeg':
            return 'image/jpeg';
        case '.png':
            return 'image/png';
        case '.webp':
            return 'image/webp';
        case '.map':
            return 'binary/octet-stream'
        default:
            return 'application/octet-stream'    
    }
};

(async() => {
    const file = './index.html';
    const params = {
        Bucket: 'myBucket',
        Key: file,
        Body: createReadStream(file),
        ContentType: getMimeType(extname(file)),
    };
    await s3.putObject(params).promise();
})();
```

Comment: For anyone copying this, make sure to update `webp` and `map` to `.webp` and `.map`.

Comment: Good find, updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently had the same issue popping up, the problem was a change of behavior of CloudFront & S3 Origin,
If your S3Bucket is configured to serve a static website, you need to change your origin to be the HTTPS:// endpoint instead of picking the S3 origin from the pulldown, if you are using terraform, your origin should be aws_s3_bucket.var.**website_endpoint** instead of aws_s3_bucket.var.**bucket_domain_name**

Refer to the [AWS documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDomainName)

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this issue and the root cause seems to be that object versioning was enabled.  After disabling versioning on the bucket the index HTML was served as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've been through the same issue and I have resolved this way.
At S3 Bucket, click o index.html checkbox, click con Actions tab, Edit Metadata, and you will notice that in Metadata options says "Type: System defined, Key: Content-Type, Value: binary/octet-stream".
Change **Value** and put "html" and save the changes.
Then click at index.html, "Open" button.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for uploading a directory (including subdirectories) to s3 while setting the content-type.

```
locals {
  mime_types = {
    ".html" = "text/html"
    ".css" = "text/css"
    ".js" = "application/javascript"
    ".ico" = "image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
    ".jpeg" = "image/jpeg"
    ".png" = "image/png"
    ".svg" = "image/svg+xml"
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_object" "upload_assets" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.www_bucket.bucket
  for_each = fileset(var.build_path, "**")
  key = each.value
  source = "${var.build_path}/${each.value}"
  content_type = lookup(local.mime_types, regex("\\.[^.]+$", each.value), null)
  etag = filemd5("${var.build_path}/${each.value}")
}
```

`var.build_path` is the directory containing your assets. This line:

```
content_type = lookup(local.mime_types, regex("\\.[^.]+$", each.value), null)
```

gets the file extension by matching the regex and then use provided locals map to lookup the correct `content_type`

Credit: https://engineering.statefarm.com/blog/terraform-s3-upload-with-mime/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [AWS S3 Bitbucket Pipelines Python](https://bitbucket.org/awslabs/amazon-s3-bitbucket-pipelines-python), then add the parameter ***content_type*** as follow:

**s3_upload.py**

```py
def upload_to_s3(bucket, artefact, bucket_key, content_type):
...

def main():
...
    parser.add_argument("content_type", help="Content Type File")
...

if not upload_to_s3(args.bucket, args.artefact, args.bucket_key, args.content_type):
```

and modify **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** as follow:

```sh
...
- python s3_upload.py bucket_name file key content_type 
...
```

Where **content_type** param can be one of following: [MIME types (IANA media types)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Answer (score 0):

For the Terraform > 1.6 versions using the content-type as said above:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "files" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.resume_bucket.bucket

  for_each = fileset("C:\\Users\\terraform-aws\\${each.value}", "**")
  key=each.key
  # The source directory on local machine.
  source = "C:\\Users\\terraform-aws\\${each.value}"
  content_type = each.value
  etag = filemd5("C:\\Users\\terraform-aws\\${each.value}")

}
```