# My website hosted Amazon S3 downloads index.html though my content-type is type/html

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, website-hosting

Similar Question: [Amazon S3 downloads index.html instead of serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296875/amazon-s3-downloads-index-html-instead-of-serving/55197550#55197550)

I am trying to upload a directory to my S3, when I upload manually I can see as static web page. But when I upload using curl, the index.html is getting downloaded.

When I curl my request `curl -I https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/index.html`, I can see

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
x-amz-request-id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 21:03:50 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 20:53:05 GMT
ETag: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 48210
Server: AmazonS3
```

But still the index.html is downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the [relevant bucket for website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html):

> 1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at
>      https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
> 2. In the list, choose the bucket that you want to use for your hosted
>      website.
> 3. Choose the Properties tab.
> 4. Choose Static website hosting, and then choose Use this bucket to host
>      a website.
> 5. You are prompted to provide the index document and any optional error
>      documents and redirection rules that are needed.
>
> For information about what an index document is, see [Configuring Index
>   Document Support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html).

Comment: Update: When I tried to hit the link on an incognito window, I can see the html as webpage. But few css are missing. 

Thanks for the reply @esqew, I have enabled website hosting for my bucket and I am able to host a static web page now, but I see some css rendering issues. I am uploading css file with this content-type="text/css". Is there any way to upload all type of files to S3 with common headers.

Comment: You might need to provide more specific details or ask another question; what errors are you seeing in the browser console?

Comment: I can see the webpage on browser but not with correct styling. I opted to upload files to S3 using AWS CLI and it is working fine now. I can see my static web page with correct styling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the file on AWS S3 console and go to Properties tab details of the file, you will see Metadata section

Remove the existing "Content-Type" metadata entry and retype it as "text/html"

If you have configured your S3 as a static web site hosting, now the file will be displayed with its HTML content instead of forcing the browser to download it