# S3 Static site downloads index.html after uploading files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, static-site

I have a static site that I served to s3 called tidbitstatistics.com

I wrote a script using boto3 to replace the files with new ones and since then, my site doesn't open - instead it downloads the index.html file.

From what I can tell, I didn't change any settings. The site was working fine before I re-uploaded the files. Since then, I deleted all the files and re-uploaded them manually, but I am still running into the same error.

I thought this might have to do with the file types, but they were the correct `text/html` file types when re-uploading manually and I am adjusting my script to specify file types when calling `put_object` instead of `upload_file` with boto3.

Static site hosting is turned on for that bucket and public permissions to read are set. I'm just not sure how s3 all of a sudden won't serve my static site.

I followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296875/amazon-s3-downloads-index-html-instead-of-serving), but I don't see a Content-Disposition property.

Any help would be appreciated - web development is not my strong suit!

Comment: As of the typing of this message, your site works.  It's possible you just needed to clear out your browser's cache after fixing the MIME types.

Comment: @AnonCoward yes, that was the issue. thanks so much!